# Does Ethylene Triple response provide any advantage to the Arabidopsis thaliana Etiloated seedling,?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

As ethylene has a triple response effect on  Arabidopsis thaliana Etiloated seedling-

1 Shortening and thickening of Hypocotyl

2 Exaggerated apical hook

3 Short root

According to [this site](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Botany/Botany_(Ha_Morrow_and_Algiers)/Unit_3%3A_Plant_Physiology_and_Regulation/16%3A_Hormones/16.05%3A_Ethylene)

> Ethylene mediates the triple response, which makes the shoots of
> seedlings that are buried under debris grow short and wide as well as
> bend horizontally. This makes it possible for the shoot to push
> through the debris.

I am not able to comprehend how this response of apical hook ,shortening can possibly help plant escape that condition? Does this response has some real benefit to plant or just a side effect of no importance to the plant, Although it was very helpful to the scientist